# Vue.js: How do I convert specific data in a given object?

Tags: vue.js

In my vue.js file I receive via the backend an JSON encoded object. The output of the data are looking like this:

```
[
    {
        "start": "2020-08-19",
        "end":"2020-08-21"
    },
    {
        "start":"2020-09-15",
        "end":"2020-09-20"
    }
]
```

For the use of a datepicker I need to convert the current date with the `new Date()` function.

So how can I loop through the object, convert just the dates and put these into a new array? It's important to keep the field names.

Unfortunately I didn't find any comparable documentation and tried different solutions without success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
let array = [
  {
    start: '2020-08-19',
    end: '2020-08-21',
  },
  {
    start: '2020-09-15',
    end: '2020-09-20',
  },
];

array.map(item => {
  item.start = new Date(item.start);
  item.end = new Date(item.end);
  return item;
});

console.log(array)
```